# Cross browser scrolling issue with jquery Parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please have a look at the given below link in chrome & firefox I m Facing some weired issues

http://amaru-ventures.in/Headline_factory/

## Issue one

Scrolling is working smoothely in Firefox but in chrome it is not.

## Issuse second

On both the browsers Like on our companies the page scroll to fine but my title "OUR COMPANIES" goes below the header i want it to eb below the header.

Any help would be Appreciated

Regards

- Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `css class` that you have used for `OUR HEADLINES` and the above one ..  As  I checked in debugger they are having different `css classes` try this css class for `our headlines` `class=" sticky-wrapper"` ... I am not sure This is correct .. But I am unable to add comment there thats why I am leaving it as answer.

Comment: Thank you your solution worked have figured out the solution for smooth scroll. For those who want to know have shifted the javascript code to the bottom & it worked